# Determine where condition based on column values

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement that if I am getting data with particular column as not `null`, then I need to fetch all the records corresponding to that `source_type`, else I need to fetch all the records based on other column. Let's take the example of below record

[image]

In the above case grouping is done based on the column `GRP`. In that particular group, if `source_type` column is not `null` for any of the records, we need to fetch all the records from that group which have the same value in `SOURCE` column, where the `source_type` is not `null`. In this case the expected output is

[image]

But in case within a group if the `source_type` column is `null` for all the records, we need to fetch all the records from that group which have the same value in the `source` column where `MATCH_TYPE='MP'`.In this case the expected output is

[image]

Comment: Please fill in the remaining, third screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a nice job for analytical functions...

```
with xyz as (
    select X.*,
        count(X.source_type) over (partition by X.grp, X.source) as non_null_source_type#,
        first_value(case when X.match_type = 'MP' then X.source end) over (partition by X.grp) as source_from_mp$
    from table X
)
select *
from xyz
where non_null_source_type# > 0
    or non_null_source_type# = 0
        and source = source_from_mp$
;
```

... in case I understood your use case correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the query.I am really sorry to say that ,I am not getting the result as expected.

Comment: @GIN, that's because you did not phrase your question properly and thoroughly.